# Reading exponential number from excel in java

Tags: java, excel, csv

I have an excel file which I am reading using CSVReader which has a cell value as 1.2346E+011.After reading this cell value its coming as 1.2346E+011 but after checking the exact value in excel it comes to 123456789012.I need to store the exact value 123456789012 not 1.2346E+011 in my table.

The vendor is filling the excel sheet and is saving it as .CSV.
Can Anyone help in this?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: how is the value in the csv file? (just basic check)

Comment: Format the column as a number in Excel *before* saving the file as CSV.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to *format* the cells in Excel to display the `123456789012` format. This should get exported to the CSV and you can read it with the `CSVReader`

Alternatively, you might want to look to [POI](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html), a Java library which allows you to read `xls` and `xlsx` Excel files.

Answer (score 0):

The number is intact: Excel is *formatting* the number like that.

To override that behaviour, highlight the entire column, rows, etc. right click, choose Format Cells, and choose "Number" as the category.